# How can I install matplotlib without installing Qt using conda on Windows?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, conda

I wrote a simple GUI application in tkinter that uses matplotlib. Given that I don't make any use of the Qt backend, I guess I don't need it for my application so I'd prefer not to include it in my conda environment: I need my environment to be as much light-weight as possible. Unfortunately the command "conda install matplotlib" installs Qt by default. Is there a way to prevent this?

I'm using anaconda on Windows 10.

Comment: You can install packages without their dependencies with `conda install --no-update-dependencies package`, but whether that will break matplotlib will require some testing.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you mean `conda install --no-deps`. In lack of other options, this can be a solution.

Comment: Right, my mistake, sorry! :-)

Comment: It seems to work (at least under linux where the tkinter backend seems to be a functional enough replacement for the default backend). I have not tried on macOS and windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conda Forge offers [a `matplotlib-base` package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib-base) that does not include a Qt dependency.

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib-base
```

I can confirm that this is sufficient to generate images in Jupyter notebooks.